# Same value of latitude and longitude repeated

Tags: android, google-maps, getter-setter

I am new to android. I am developing an app in which I am getting latitude longitude from server and i want to show markers with those points on map. I am using setters and getters. But i am gettting same value of latitude and longitude repeated and the map shows only one marker. 
Here is my code.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
    empid = intent.getStringExtra("empid");

    Log.e("Maspp acctt iddd", "" + empid);
    Log.e("Maspp acctt dateeeee", "" + date);
    mapp = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    new NetCheck().execute();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}

private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < mapp.size(); i++) {
            Double lati = Double.parseDouble(pojo.getLat().toString());
            Double longi = Double.parseDouble(pojo.getLongg().toString());
            String dattme = pojo.getDateTime().toString();
            dest = new LatLng(lati, longi);
            if (map != null) {
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest));
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dest));
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(dest)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                        .title(""+dattme));

            }

        }
        nPregress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Log.e("beforeeeee", "");
            HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(
                    "http://url");


            httpRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            Log.e("Afetererer", "");
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            json.put("login_date", date);
            json.put("empid", empid);
            Log.i("JSON Object", json.toString());


            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            se.setContentType("application/json");

            httpRequest.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                    .getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            inputStream.close();
            strServerResponse = sb.toString();

            Log.e("Server Response", "" + strServerResponse.toString());
            Log.e("priyankaaaa","priyuaaaaaa");

            if (strServerResponse != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
                    Log.e("priyankaaa111a","priyuaa111aaaa");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        pojo = new Pojo();

                        String latitude = jsonObj.optString("Latitude");
                        String longitude = jsonObj.optString("Longitude");
                        String date_time = jsonObj.optString("date_time");
                        Log.e("Latitudeeeeee",""+latitude);
                        Log.e("longfffff",""+longitude);
                        Log.e("dateeee",""+date_time);
                        pojo.setLat(latitude);
                        pojo.setLongg(longitude);
                        pojo.setDateTime(date_time);

                        mapp.add(pojo);

                    }
```

Comment: get your `lat,lng` from `location` of  `onLocationChanged()` method

Comment: @Rustam These are not current latitude and longitude.. these are stored in database

Comment: from where you are accessing `lat,lng`? where is code?

Comment: If the latitude and longitude from server  is same then markers will be placed on top to each other thats why you are seeing only one marker.

Comment: @Niv No i have different values in database

Comment: try adding some other location to database and check. There may not be any error in your code. Please do a try and reply

Comment: @Rustam I am accessing these in doInBackground()

Comment: @Niv Yes i have added but still not showing

Comment: what is your `Server Response`?

Comment: @Rustam this is Server Response﹕ [{"date_time":"2015:10:01 12:45:42","Latitude":"21.161674","Longitude":"21.161674"},{"date_time":"2015:10:01 12:40:35","Latitude":"21.1342007","Longitude":"79.1252174"},{"date_time":"2015:10:01 11:40:32","Latitude":"21.789555","Longitude":"79.04785"},{"date_time":"2015:10:01 10:40:42","Latitude":"21.121236","Longitude":"79.04512"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is that you instead of getting the json object at each index you are getting just the first one. 
Therefore, get the json object at the index you want and then parse the data.

Comment: Thanks I have changed it but still map shows only one marker

Comment: @Pri, it looks you are doing the same mistake in creating the markers as well.

Comment: Next, see how far are the locations from each other.